# Switch View with animation

Tags: ios, uiview, viewwillappear, viewdidappear

I must change a view. In a view I've a button with this code:

```
    FormazioneViewController *formazioneC = [[FormazioneViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FormazioneView" bundle:nil];

self.formazioneViewController= formazioneC;

[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop)];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];

[self viewWillDisappear:YES];
[self viewDidDisappear:YES];
[self.view addSubview:formazioneViewController.view];
[formazioneViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
[formazioneViewController viewDidAppear:YES];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

and I add a superview, now i must return in this view and i use a button with this code:

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop)];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];

[self viewWillDisappear:YES];
[self viewDidDisappear:YES];

[self.view removeFromSuperview];

[****** viewWillAppear:YES];
[****** viewDidAppear:YES];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

What is the object where i must call the viewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear method??
Thanks

Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: No need to call `viewWillAppear` and `ViewDidAppear` it will automatically gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Have you Written this method,

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: also write this `[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];`

Comment: where I must add this? in the botton method??

Comment: after this line `[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];` and where you want animation write this line.

Comment: where is `animationDidStop` method ?

Comment: there isn't the method animationDidStop!

Comment: what you want ? i am not getting your question. *i thought you want to navigate to a new page with animation*

Comment: I've 2 view with two nib file! I must switch the view with animation. When I press the first botton the animation work and I see the second view, but when i click the button in the second view the animation doesn't work because I've not the object for call the method viewWillAppear:YES and ViewDidAppear:YES

Comment: inside your second view, when you click button inside button click method write: `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`